# Separating strings in a single line

Tags: visual-studio

How do I separate the single line of input into 3 different variables without using arrays? (x,y,z) Each section is separated by a space

Ex. 184 41890 42891

The code I have so far is just reading the line one character at a time in a loop.

```
    c = Chr(reader.Read)
    s = ""
    Do While (ch <> vbCr) And (ch <> Chr(32)) And (reader.Peek <> -1)
        Select Case c
            Case "0" To "9"
                s = s & c
            Case Else
                MsgBox("Error")
        End Select
        c = Chr(reader.Read)
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to avoid using arrays altogether or just end up with the parts in specific strings? You can do this:

```
        string input = "184 41890 42891";
        string[] parts = input.Split(' ');
        string myCustomString1 = parts[0];
        string myCustomString2 = parts[1];
        string myCustomString3 = parts[2];
```

This has problems though because you need to know how many parts there will be so that you can have enough strings set up. The advantage of arrays is that they are flexible and can be whatever size you wish.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using arrays altogether. I'm trying to split them up because I want to use the x,y,z in another calculation. There's going to be many lines of input (same format). If the calculation is included within the loop, can I just keep re-using the same 3 variables instead of making new ones?

Comment: Yes you can reuse the variables by defining them outside of the loop. Are all the input strings only three segments, and always separated with spaces?

Comment: Yes It would look exactly like the example input, just with different numbers